# Twig zebra-stripping without loop

Tags: if-statement, twig

I have a table whose rows are generated dynamically depending on users' input (it is a summary of charges that may or may not take a promo code--if the user have one--and a gift message--if the user sends one). There is no way to generate the items of the summary of charges on a loop since the items come from different places in my application. I only have conditionals for the items to appear or not on the users' order depending on what the order is like. The table needs to have zebra-stripping. Because the number of items may vary, I cannot hardcode the color inline (it is an e-mail). I tried twig's divisibleby and modulo on the rows, so the colors would alternate for even and odd rows. Although the color changes it does not change to the color I want and it is not doing the zebra stripping (all rows change to blue. I need colors to alternate between light beige (#fcf9f5) and white (#ffffff)). What am I missing?

Here is the code for one tr:

```
{% set index = 0 %}                         
    <tr bgcolor="{% if index is divisibleby(2) %} #fcf9f5 {% else %}  #ffffff {% endif %}">
        <td align="left" style="height: 30px; width: 273px; padding-left: 40px;">
            <span style="font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-weight: 500;">Order Subtotal:</span>    
        </td>

        <td align="left" style="height: 30px; width: 273px; padding-left: 40px;font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;">
            <span>{{ order.itemsTotal|sylius_price }}</span>    
        </td>                                           
    </tr>
{% index++ %}
```

Comment: please show me code before `{% set index = 0 %}` and after `{% index++ %}`. I suppose that you set `index` variable for each row.  BTW. For getting well formatted (ready for standard loop) array, you can always use twig simple functions http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: NHG, the code before "index" does not relate with the table I am trying to do the zebra striping on. I am using <tr bgcolor="{% if index is divisibleby(2) %} #fcf9f5 {% else %}  #ffffff {% endif %}"> for all rows i need to alternate colors and incrementing the index at the end of each one of them. The problem here is why the color does not match the hexadecimal I am using. I believe it may be a spacing issue. If I put spaces around the hexadecimals the color changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Twig can't correct the fact that your code is dirty.

Let's say you have 3 diferents sources. If you display them all in an array they have all comon attributes right?

you just have to combine all the source objects in a simple displayable object (a DTO).

Twig can't contain business logic, it just display stuff.

If you want to keep your logic in your view, try to use twig [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) fuction to combien your arrays and display them in a loop